# Filling in non-continuous data with zeroes - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If i've got a non-continuous dataset in the form of:

```
 x      y
7500   1.4
7501   1.45
7502   1.34
7510   1.67
7511   1.54
7512   1.89
```

What is the quickest way to fill in all the intervening x-values with zeroes? Or to do so between a range i.e. specify a range of 7490-7515 and the output is:

```
 x      y
7490   1.4
7491   0
7492   0
7493   0
7494   0
7495   0
7496   0
7497   0
7498   0
7499   0
7500   1.4
7501   1.45
7502   1.34
7503   0
7504   0
7505   0
7506   0
7507   0
7508   0
7509   0
7510   1.67
7511   1.54
7512   1.89
7513   0
7514   0
7515   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize it with zeros and then assign the nonzero data points into it.

```
x2 = [7490:7515]';  % #'
y2 = zeros(size(x2));
[tf,ix] = ismember(x,x2);
y2(ix(tf)) = y(tf);
```

If you know all `x` are present in `x2`, you can skip the `(tf)` subsetting. And if all your `x` values are integers >= `x2(1)`, you can optimize away the expensive `ismember()` by doing an index shift, like so.

```
[lo,hi] = deal(7490, 7515);
x2 = [lo:hi]';  % #'
y2 = zeros(size(x2));
ix = x - lo + 1;
y2(ix) = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty efficient as it uses one lightweight function call to `zeros`, which is just necessary in this case and another lightweight call to `numel`. Rest of the code is all about `matrix-indexing`. Here's the code -

```
%// Define range
range1 = 7490:7515

%// Setup output array and initialize the first column with range values
out = [range1.' zeros(numel(range1),1)]  %//'

%// Put A(:,2) values into the second column of output array indexed by the
%// offsets decided by the first column of A w.r.t. the starting range value
out( A(:,1)-range1(1)+1 , 2) = A(:,2)
```

Please note that it assumes `A` as the input `non-continuous dataset`.

---

If you want to go a bit *experimental*, you can use a [`hacky pre-allocation scheme`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) to do something like this -

```
range1 = 7490:7515

clear out
out(numel(range1),2) = 0
out(:,1) = range1
out( A(:,1)-range1(1)+1 , 2) = A(:,2)
```